# Group column using variance range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Hi i'm trying to group a column by values that are closer each other, as example:

```
column1 column2
322      a
326      b
323      c
323      d
323      e
324      f
325      g
498      h
498      i
495      j
496      k
```

I want group column1 using values with variance +- 3

Result:

```
column1 , column2
323 (+-3) a,b,c,d,e,f,g
495 (+-3) h,i,j,k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the value  by `sort_values` then using `diff` and `cumsum` create the groupkey

```
df=df.sort_values('column1')
df.sort_index().\
    groupby(df.column1.diff().gt(3).cumsum()).\
      agg({'column1':'first','column2':','.join})
         column1        column2
column1                        
0            322  a,b,c,d,e,f,g
1            498        h,i,j,k
```

Comment: Work perfect! Thanks!

Comment: If i would like to sorting values of *column2* using a *column3*, How can be that possible? @WenYoBen Can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695396/group-column-using-difference-and-sorting-one-column-by-other-column-in-pandas