# Group column using difference and sorting one column by other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i'm trying to group a column by values that are closer each other, and then sorting another column by the values of other, example:

```
column1 column2 column3
322   16   a
326   11   b
323   22   c
323   26   d
323   20   e
324   15   f
325   18   g
498   20   h
498   30   i
495   22   j
496   15   k
```

I want group column1 using values with variance +- 3 and sorting ascending  the column2

Result:

```
column1 , column2
323 (+-3) b,f,a,g,e,c,d
495 (+-3) k,h,j,i
```

Because we have

(b,11) , (f,15) , (a,16) , (g,18) , (e,20) , (c,22) , (d,26)
(k,15) , (h,20) , (j,22) , (i,30)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case , we need create another help key after `sort_values` with `cumsum` and `diff`

```
s=df.sort_values(['column1'])
s['New']=s.column1.diff().gt(3).cumsum()
s=s.sort_values(['New','column2'])
s.groupby('New').agg({'column1':'first','column3':','.join})
     column1        column3
New                        
0        326  b,f,a,g,e,c,d
1        496        k,h,j,i
```